# Scraping links in a para using BS

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
<p class="graytext">2012 Transcripts</p>
<blockquote><p><a title="October 3, 2012 Debate Transcript" href="/voter-education/debate-transcripts/october-3-2012-debate-transcript/">October 3, 2012: The First Obama-Romney Presidential Debate</a></p>
<p><a href="/voter-education/debate-transcripts/october-11-2012-the-biden-romney-vice-presidential-debate/">October 11, 2012: The Biden-Ryan Vice Presidential Debate</a></p>
<p><a href="/voter-education/debate-transcripts/october-16-2012-the-second-obama-romney-presidential-debate/">October 16, 2012: The Second Obama-Romney Presidential Debate</a></p>
<p><a href="/voter-education/debate-transcripts/october-22-2012-the-third-obama-romney-presidential-debate/">October 22, 2012: The Third Obama-Romney Presidential Debate</a></p></blockquote>
<hr />
<p class="graytext">2008 Transcripts</p>
<blockquote><p><a title="September 26, 2008 Debate Transcript" href="/voter-education/debate-transcripts/2008-debate-transcript/">September 26, 2008: The First McCain-Obama Presidential Debate</a></p>
<p><a title="October 2, 2008 Debate Transcript" href="/voter-education/debate-transcripts/2008-debate-transcript-2/">October 2, 2008: The Biden-Palin Vice Presidential Debate</a></p>
<p><a title="October 7, 2008 Debate Transcript" href="/voter-education/debate-transcripts/october-7-2008-debate-transcrip/">October 7, 2008: The Second McCain-Obama Presidential Debate</a></p>
<p><a title="October 15, 2008 Debate Transcript" href="/voter-education/debate-transcripts/october-15-2008-debate-transcript/">October 15, 2008: The Third McCain-Obama Presidential Debate</a></p></blockquote>
<hr />
<p class="graytext">2004 Transcripts</p>
<blockquote><p><a title="October 13, 2004 Debate Transcript" href="/voter-education/debate-transcripts/october-13-2004-debate-transcript/">October 13, 2004: The Third Bush-Kerry Presidential Debate</a></p>
<p><a title="October 8, 2004 Debate Transcript" href="/voter-education/debate-transcripts/october-8-2004-debate-transcript/">October 8, 2004: The Second Bush-Kerry Presidential Debate</a></p>
<p><a title="October 5, 2004 Transcript" href="/voter-education/debate-transcripts/october-5-2004-transcript/">October 5, 2004: The Cheney-Edwards Vice Presidential Debate</a></p>
<p><a title="September 30. 2004 Debate Transcript" href="/voter-education/debate-transcripts/september-30-2004-debate-transcript/">September 30, 2004: The First Bush-Kerry Presidential Debate</a></p></blockquote>
<hr />
<p class="graytext">2000 Transcripts</p>
<blockquote><p><a title="October 3, 2000 Transcript" href="/voter-education/debate-transcripts/october-3-2000-transcript/">October 3, 2000: The First Gore-Bush Presidential Debate</a></p>
<p><a title="October 5, 2000 Debate Transcript" href="/voter-education/debate-transcripts/october-5-2000-debate-transcript/">October 5, 2000: The Lieberman-Cheney Vice Presidential Debate</a></p>
<p><a title="October 11, 2000 Debate Transcript" href="/voter-education/debate-transcripts/october-11-2000-debate-transcript/">October 11, 2000: The Second Gore-Bush Presidential Debate</a></p>
<p><a title="October 17, 2000 Debate Transcript" href="/voter-education/debate-transcripts/october-17-2000-debate-transcript/">October 17, 2000: The Third Gore-Bush Presidential Debate</a></p>
<p><a title="Debate Transcript Translations" href="/voter-education/debate-transcripts/2000-debate-transcripts-translations/">The 2000 Debate Transcripts: Transcripts of the debates translated into six languages</a></p></blockquote>
<hr />
```

The question is to scrape the link which relates to the first presidential debate in 2008 and 2004,
So the answer is the first link in the blocks of 2008 and 2004 transcripts, but how do I scrape it?

Comment: in which programming language do you want this done ?.

Comment: Using python library beautifulSoup

Answer (score 1):

Import the beautiful soap dependencies.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

page = open(html_doc)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

blockquote = soup.find_all('blockquote')

for anchor in blockquote:
    if  '2004' in anchor.a['href'] or '2008' in anchor.a['href'] :
            print(anchor.a['href'])
```

Comment: It doesn't work, as I want to scrape for a particular block and not every block.
I edited the question, can you help me now?

Comment: @SejalMohata changed the solution as per question modification.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the p tag with class `graytext` with text `2004|2008` and use `find_next('a')` to get the first link after those `p` tags

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
wanted_p=soup.find_all('p',class_='graytext',text=re.compile('2008|2004'))
for p in wanted_p:
    print(p.find_next('a'))
```

Output

```
<a href="/voter-education/debate-transcripts/2008-debate-transcript/" title="September 26, 2008 Debate Transcript">September 26, 2008: The First McCain-Obama Presidential Debate</a>
<a href="/voter-education/debate-transcripts/october-13-2004-debate-transcript/" title="October 13, 2004 Debate Transcript">October 13, 2004: The Third Bush-Kerry Presidential Debate</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given you know the years you want you can use attribute = value selectors to target appropriate hrefs with `select_one`. `select_one` returns the first match.

```
debate2008 = soup.select_one("[href*='2008-debate-transcript']").text
debate2004= soup.select_one("[href*='2004-debate-transcript']").text
```